# Question about the projection of vector onto another formula

Tags: vectors

Let $v$, $u$ be some vectors. Then the projection of $v$ onto $u$ is the vector: $${{v\cdot u }\over{\Vert u\Vert^2}}u $$
Why is the following action wrong? $${{v\cdot u }\over{\Vert u\Vert^2}}u={{v\cdot u \cdot u }\over{\Vert u\Vert^2}}={{v\cdot \Vert u\Vert^2 }\over{\Vert u\Vert^2}}=v $$

I know it's wrong, I just don't understand what's the mistake.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing scalar multiplication ($\lambda \cdot u$ with $\lambda \in \mathbb K, u \in \mathbb K^n$) with inner product
($u \cdot v$ with $u,v \in \mathbb K^n$)
If you omit the $\cdot$ for scalar multiplication, your error is more obvious:
$$(v \cdot u) u \neq v (u \cdot u)$$

Comment: As AlexR points out, you are mixing the use of $\cdot$. Write the inner product using a different notation such as $<u, v>$ or avoid $\cdot$ for scalar multiplication.

Comment: Ah, thank you for your answer!

Comment: @charlie Happy to help. If this solved your question, please mark it as such; else feel free to ask further questions.

Comment: That's one reason to denote the inner product as $\langle a,b\rangle$ instead of $a\cdot b$.